# Allowing a client to specify whether parameter is Required or Preferred

Tags: rest, api-design, naming

I am enhancing an existing API to provide shipping rates for a b2b web service.  This specific endpoint returns a single rate based on matching request parameters such as the service level and package information to choose the best option.  We currently support allowing the client pass in a carrier on the request, and it will then only select a rate from that carrier.  However, in some cases the requested carrier does not offer a matching service, and the business has requested that we now allow this service to substitute the requested carrier for a different carrier that can satisfy the request, but only in certain circumstances.

I am planning to add a field to the request that allows the client to specify whether their requested carrier is absolutely required or just preferred, so that they know whether to expect an error or a substitution if that carrier cannot be used.  However, I am not sure if this is the right way to do it, as it is not a common pattern, and I don't really know what to call such a field.  Which of these options would seem most correct?

1. A new field on the request which has an enum of `[required, preferred]` as possible values.  *What would this field be called?*
2. Two separate fields `requiredCarrier` and `preferredCarrier` in something like an OpenAPI `oneOf` so that only one of the two can be passed in from the client.  *This may require a new major version of the API.*
3. A structural change to the requested carrier field to make it an object with multiple properties, such as `requestedCarrier: { carrier: 'FedEx', isRequired: true }`.   *This would definitely require a new major version of the API.*

Answer (score 2):

> I am planning to add a field to the request that allows the client to specify whether their requested carrier is absolutely required or just preferred, so that they know whether to expect an error or a substitution if that carrier cannot be used.

As a carrier that isn't required is implicitly preferred, tagging a carrier as preferred is unnecessary. All you need is a boolean field whether the carrier is required.

- If the field is present and set to `true`, it is required.
- If the field is present and set to `false` it isn't required, thus it is preferred.
- If the field is missing, the default applies. The default is whatever the API does at the moment, thus the change is backward compatible.

How to name such a field? How about `isRequired`?

Comment: The biggest issue I have here is making sure the client would understand what `isRequired` does.  The object with the carrier on it has several other fields such as `serviceLevel`, `features`, etc.  That's why in my option #3 above, I put an `isRequried` field inside the carrier object, but that's a bigger change to the spec.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach You can also name it `carrierIsRequired` and not put it into the carrier object. As for understanding, only the implementer needs to understand it, and usually that's what documentation is for. Trying to guess how an API works or what a property does by its name is a **horrible idea**. Don't ever do that! Programming is about knowing, not about guessing. As for "requiring major version", it doesn't since the field is optional. Existing clients continue to work as they used to if they just don't set this field at all, so it's a minor update (new feature).

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach, Why is adding an optional field to the carrier object a bigger change than adding a similar field to the object containing the carrier object?